# how to minimize output resistance

Tags: transistors, motor, speed

I want to setting up a micro coreless motor (5*20 size) for quadcopter.

[image: schematic of circuit]

I use BD139 transistor, PWM from STM32 (31kHz PWM frequency) and 500mA li-polymer battery for this work, but the maximum speed of motor is not enough.

When I connect the battery to the motor directly, its speed is very good. However when I use the transistor with PWM, this speed reduces. I know that it is due to output resistance of the transistor.

What should I do to increase the maximum speed of the motor, when I use a transistor?

Do you know a better transistor or driver for this work?

Comment: If your PWM duty cycle less than 100%, it is expected that the motor will run slower than directly from the battery. And the thing you are talking about is not the "output resistance" but the non-zero Vce voltage drop on the transistor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly the choice of the flyback diode (presumably a 1N4001 to 1N4007 part). It will adequately catch the back emf of the motor (when the transistor switches off) but it will remain conducting for up to 30 us (supplier dependent) when the transistor reactivates. This means that you will get poor currrent consumption if the PWM frequency is above a few kHz. Use a high speed diode.

Secondly, if the PWM waveform is less than 100% then you won't get full speed compared to connecting the motor directly the battery.

Thirdly, you don't indicate how much base current you are activating the BD139 with. If you want it turn turn on well and saturate you need to be thinking about feeding the base with in excess of 50 mA and your driver may not be able to deliver this. Also, when fed with that current at the base you will get a volt drop from collector to emitter of 0.1 to 0.5 volts with a collector current of only 0.5 amps.

It's not really designed for switching applications and I would recommend you look at using a MOSFET.

Comment: I can't think of a single good reason to use a BD139 now that the 1970s are over.

Comment: @MarcusMüller are they? Nobody told me lol.

Comment: yeah. I was confused too, what with all the Russian-American meddling in world politics going on.

Comment: And then America will back a new group called the Mujahideen (in order to provoke Russia) and not really understand that it'll morph into the Taliban and then were in the 1990s all over again.

Comment: um, oh, err: yay??